# Parse expression with double coefficient values in mathdotnet

Tags: c#, math.net

I am using `Infix.Parse` to parse equations like

```
apples + oranges = 2
Expression aleft = Infix.ParseOrThrow("apples + oranges");
Expression aright = Infix.ParseOrThrow("2");
```

Sometimes I need to parse fractional values, like

```
2.5*tax + income = 30.5
```

But this throws a `System.Exception`

```
Error in ...
(2.5)
  ^
Expecting: infix operator or ')'
```

There must be a way to handle such expressions in mathdotnet, but I cannot find it in the documentation. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algebraic expressions can contain integers and rational numbers, but not floating-point numbers (neither in actual algebra nor in Math.NET Symbolics). You can either use a [symbol until evaluation](http://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/#Evaluating-Expressions) or use exact rational numbers instead.

However, one could argue that "30.5" can be interpreted as a shorthand for "305/10", or "61/2" after auto-simplification. We could consider to extend the parser to automatically do this interpretation, maybe with a setting to turn it on/off. Could you [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/issues) for this? Thanks!

So, to answer the actual question, until we've extended the parser you'll have to use rational numbers instead, e.g. `25/10*tax + income`, which gets auto-simplified to `income + (5/2)*tax`.

Comment: Update: the parser has been extended accordingly in MathNet.Symbolics-v0.5.0 released today.